# I get confused to determine which relationship is appropriate (is it one-to-one or one-to-many)

Tags: mysql, one-to-many, entity-relationship, one-to-one

I am trying to create a CMS website that has many types (raw_unit_type) of media (such as video, article, sound) to post about topic or issue and this media has another type (unit_type).

for example:
media file named x is a 'video' type and this x has another type named 'collection'.
media file named y is a 'video' type and this y has another type named 'comparison'.
media file named z is a 'article' type and this z has another type named 'collection'.

Now

I get stucked when determining which relationship is appropriate to my case between these two tables as in the figure[image]

It should be one-to-one or one-to-many relationship ? that's my question with explaining.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can a `raw_unit_type` have multiple `unit_types` or just exact one? E.g. is it possible to have a `video` with the fictional `unit_types`: `collection`, `holidays`?

Comment: unit_type can have multiple unit_types not only one

Comment: This looks like a many-to-many relation. If both 'video' and 'article' can have a 'collection' that's many-to-one, but if also 'video' can have multiple unit_type ('collection', 'comparison'), that's one-to-many. 
one-to-many + many-to-one = many-to-many

Comment: So then it should be `many-to-many`. One `raw_unit_type` can have mutliple `unit_types`, but one `unit_type` has only one `raw_unit_type`, if you only look at one relationship. But the same `unit_type` can also occur in another relationship where the `raw_unit_type` differs. Anyways it is absolutely not a `one-to-one` relationship.

Comment: @verhie
**raw_unit_type** (e.g. video) can not have multiple **unit_type**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a `many-to-many` relationship.  You will need a joining table between these two tables, because a `raw_unit_type` ("video") can have many `unit_types` ("collection", "comparison", etc) and `unit_types` can belong to many `raw_unit_types`.